# Extract node value from an xml from a table using SQL

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

```
<Recording xmlns="http://www.m5net.com/test/configuration/connectors" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Id>16607</Id>
  <Mode>1</Mode>
  <Enable>true</Enable>
  <Notification i:nil="true" />
  <Notify>false</Notify>
</Recording>
```

I need to extract the value of mode . This is config column from a ModeConfiguration table .

I have tried

```
SELECT
config.Value('(/Recording//Mode)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as int
FROM ModeConfiguration
```

but looks like the namespace is not getting considered correctly .

Comment: I dont see any XML tag for:  CallRecordingMode  ??

Comment: corrected the description : SELECT
config.Value('(/Recording//Mode)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as int
FROM ModeConfiguration

Answer (score 2):

The default namespace should be taken into account.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @ModeConfiguration TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, config XML);
INSERT INTO @ModeConfiguration (config) VALUES
(N'<Recording xmlns="http://www.m5net.com/test/configuration/connectors"
           xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Id>16607</Id>
    <Mode>1</Mode>
    <Enable>true</Enable>
    <Notification i:nil="true"/>
    <Notify>false</Notify>
</Recording>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.m5net.com/test/configuration/connectors')
SELECT c.value('(Id/text())[1]', 'INT') AS Id
    , c.value('(Mode/text())[1]', 'INT') AS Mode
FROM @ModeConfiguration
    CROSS APPLY config.nodes('/Recording') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+-------+------+
|  Id   | Mode |
+-------+------+
| 16607 |    1 |
+-------+------+
```

**Screen shot**
[image]

Good link on the subject of typed XML: [text() dilemma for typed XML vs. untyped XML](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/fun-with-static-xquery-evaluation-1/)

Comment: I tried out this solution but it doesn't work :

'text()' is not supported on simple typed or 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyType' elements.

If the other name space also need to be  handled -" xmlns:i " or anything else I am missing out.

Comment: @user11403920. Ii seems that your XML has a different structure. Or your column is bound to an XML Schema (XSD). That's why it is important to provide a minimal reproducible example while asking a question. I added a screen shot to the answer.

Comment: @user11403920, I added a link on the subject of querying typed XML.

Answer (score 0):

this worked :

```
select t.node.value('*:Mode[1]', 'int')
from ModeConfiguration 
    CROSS APPLY Config.nodes('*:Recording') t(node)
    WHERE  featurei=27;
```

Comment: Also try to cast XML as a varchar and look for a similar value :

SELECT top 1000 * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE  CAST(column as nvarchar(max)) LIKE 'check this'